# How does encoding as a bit string in Genetic algorithm helpful?

Tags: encoding, genetic-algorithm, bitstring

Suppose we have to solve a global optimization problem in which we have to find values of 5 variables, all of which are integers. Assume we get following two parent chromosomes,

Parent 1: 6, 10, 3, 5, 12

Parent 2: 12, 10, 3, 8, 11

If we do cross-over after first 2 elements, we get following

Child 1: 6, 10, 3, 8, 11

Child 2: 12, 10, 3, 5, 12

Here we can clearly see the children are related to parents.

But when we encode as bit strings, then each chromosome is encoded as a single string of bits and we can, at random, choose any point for crossover. I do not see how this is any more beneficial than completely randomly picking any trial solutions.

I have a similar question with mutation. We randomly flip a bit. If the bit flipped has a small place value, then the change will be small. But if it has a big place value, the change will be big. How is it better than completely randomly changing a chromosome?

Comment: You're correct. Converting to a bit string is usually not helpful. Sometimes it's OK. Mostly not.

Answer (score 0):

Binary encoding is still common mainly because first works about GA used that encoding.

Furthermore it's often space efficient: `[6, 10, 3, 5, 12]` represented as a sequence of integers would probably require `5 * 32` bits; for a bit string representation `5 * 4` bits are enough (assuming numbers in the `[0;15]` range).

Under this aspect the [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) is the best case for the bit string representation (each bit says if the corresponding object is in the knapsack).

> we can, at random, choose any point for crossover. I do not see how this is any more beneficial than completely randomly picking any trial solutions

In general choosing a crossover point *in the middle of a digit* introduces an essentially arbitrary mutation of that digit with a destructive (negative) effect.

There is a nice example about this effect in the *Local Search Algorithms and Optimization Problems - Genetic Algorithms* section of **Artificial Intelligence - A modern approach** (Russel, Norvig).

Take also a look at a [similar question on Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/339705/149904).